# How to display image on all content pages ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have put this on my MasterPage in my application if i stay on my default page then the image displayed but when i go on another page image not display . Can you help me why this is not working on another page.

```
<ul  id="scroller">
   <div class="serv"> <a href="#"  onmouseover="document.wordpress.src='images/wordpress-development_red.png'" onmouseout="document.wordpress.src='images/wordpress-development.png'"> <img src="images/wordpress-development.png" name="wordpress"><br />
       WORDPRESS </a>
  </div>

  <div class="serv1"> <a href="#"  onmouseover="document.Android.src='images/mobil-app-development_red.png'" onmouseout="document.Android.src='images/mobil-app-development.png'"> <img src="images/mobil-app-development.png" name="Android"/><br />
      Android</a>
 </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect that the url to your image is wrong. Since you have hardcoded it this is not surprising. You should **never** hardcode urls in an ASP.NET MVC application. You should **always** use url helpers:

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.wordpress.src='@Url.Content("~/images/wordpress-development_red.png")'" onmouseout="document.wordpress.src='@Url.Content("~/images/wordpress-development.png")'">
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/wordpress-development.png")" name="wordpress">
    <br />
    WORDPRESS 
</a>
```

and if you are using the WebForms view engine (please tag your question appropriately so that we don't have to be guessing this):

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.wordpress.src='<%= Url.Content("~/images/wordpress-development_red.png") %>'" onmouseout="document.wordpress.src='<%= Url.Content("~/images/wordpress-development.png") %>'">
    <img src="<%= Url.Content("~/images/wordpress-development.png") %>" name="wordpress">
    <br />
    WORDPRESS 
</a>
```